# Tinkerpop - Titan/Cassandra project setup

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, cassandra, titan, tinkerpop

I am setting up a Java Enterprise 1.7 project that uses TinkerPop 3 and Titan 0.5 with Cassandra.

The general idea is to have :

1. a dedicated database server that runs Titan 0.5,
2. Tinkerpop 3 *somewhere*
3. an Application Server that runs a Java EE 7 application separated from the Database server.

I have many open questions and I would like to ask for **best practices**, **suggestions**, **examples**.

1. Where should Tinkerpop 3 stay? in the Application Server or in the Database Server?
2. How Tinkerpop communicate with Titan?
3. What is the best configuration for such environment for Tinkerpop with Titan?
4. How Java Enterprise application should communicate with Tinkerpop?
5. How should be Tinkerpop API integrated with Java EE? Please keep in mind multiple user at same time and general Enterprise envirnment issues (caching, trandactions, multiple call to the database, etc)
6. Do you have any Project setup example?

This base configuration will be eventually put in github ot bitbucket ready for other project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Titan is kind of like a database but also kind of like a GraphDB driver. I say this because no matter what configuration you choose, Titan will be using another DB as the storage backend. Current options are BerkeleyDB, HBase, and Cassandra. [This page](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra) describes the system architecture options for Cassandra.

I use [remote server mode](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Using-Cassandra#remote-server-mode) for java web apps. I run Cassandra separately and I use Titan in each application server to communicate w/ Cassandra via thrift (Titan also supports astyanax). I create a single TitanGraph instance and inject it (via factory bean wrapper) in to any Service Beans that need access to the graph.

TitanGraph will take care of both Transaction-level and DB-level caching. This is configurable.

TitanGraph will handle concurrent operations. The key is to get your transactions right. You can probably get started by having transactions exist 1:1 w/ requests. Keep in mind that read operations also occur in a transaction (this sometimes confuses newcomers).

I stick w/ the Blueprints API (TinkerPop) as much as possible, but usually I need to do some Titan-specific things - typically related to search. I commonly use TinkerPop for:

- [Gremlin](http://gremlindocs.com/)! (which I actually [do in Groovy source files](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Groovy#java-classes-talking-to-groovy-classes-with-gremlin) so I get full Gremlin sweetness),
- [Graph strategies](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/current/#_graph_strategy)
- Populating TinkerGraph instances w/ sub-graphs.

(That's just a short list of examples, but it's the things I almost always do.)

<s>I don't have a public project example but I really should. Maybe I'll have time to throw something up this weekend.</s>

[Here is an example web app](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan-web-example) that uses Spring, JAX-RS, and Jersey.

Comment: Really usefull info!
I hope you will find the time to share a public project example!

Comment: Only one thing to add: Titan 0.5 is not compatible with TP3, only with TP2. Titan 0.9 (next release) will work with TP3.

Comment: @AndreaT I added a link to titan-web-example.